# Bound on the entries of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We consider $M$ to be an $n\times n$ matrix with entries in $\mathbb C$. The goal is to determine a real constant $c$ such that for all $k \geq 0$ we have
$|(M^k)_{ij}| \leq c^k$. Namely, the modulus of the $i,j$th entry of the $k$th power of the matrix $M$ is bounded by the constant $c$ to the power of $k$.

My thinking was to perhaps utilize induction on $k$, but couldn't seem to get anywhere. The statement is obvious for $k = 0$ and $k=1$, but giving a universal constant that bounds all entries seems to be a difficult task, so I was looking for some direction or help with how to prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $a,b\in\mathbb{C}^n$, let $\langle a,b\rangle=\sum_{j=1}^n a_j\overline{b}_j$ be the inner product. Let $\|a\|=\sqrt{\langle a,a\rangle}$. Define $$\|M\|=\max\{\|Ma\|:\|a\|\leqslant 1\},$$ which is the operator norm of the operator $a\mapsto Ma$. This means $\|Ma\|\leqslant \|M\|\|a\|$ for all $a\in\mathbb{C}^n$.  Then \begin{align*} \|M^ka\| & =\|MM^{k-1}a\|\leqslant \|M\|\|M^{k-1}a\|=\|M\|\|MM^{k-2}a\|\leqslant \|M\|^2\|M^{k-2}a\| \\ & \leqslant \ldots  \leqslant \|M\|^k.\end{align*}  From this it follows that $\|M^k\|\leqslant \|M\|^k$ for all $k$.

By Cauchy-Schwarz, $|\langle a,b\rangle|\leqslant \|a\|\|b\|$ for any $a,b\in\mathbb{C}^n$. Since $\|e_i\|,\|e_j\|=1$, where $e_k$ is the vectors whose $k^{th}$ coordinate is $1$ and all other coordinates are zero, it follows that for any $i,j$, $$|(M^k)_{ij}| =|\langle M^k e_i,e_j\rangle|\leqslant \|M^k e_i\|\|e_j\|\leqslant \|M^k\|\|e_i\|\|e_j\|=\|M^k\|\leqslant \|M\|^k\|a\|.$$

So we finish with $c=\|M\|$.